# adb pull file for a specific user

Tags: android, adb, storage, multi-user

I need to pull files to PC from my Google Pixel with Android 7.1.1.

There are two users setup. Now I'm logged in as Second user.

The path to the file as seen by File Explorers seems like

```
/storage/emulated/13/APKs/file.apk
```

When I do

```
adb pull /sdcard/APKs/file.apk
```

I get file does not exist error.

Or even when i do

```
adb shell
```

I am able to only access the files of the First User and not Second User by which Im logged in.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any direct solution to the problem.
But

> /sdcard/Android/obb

folder is shared between users.
So first copy required file to the location above.
then

> adb pull /sdcard/Android/obb/filename

does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot /sdcard/.

> `adb pull /storage/emulated/13/sdcard/APKs/file.apk`